# Fetch request returning status cors and readable stream

Tags: javascript, http, fetch

I am making a fetch call to my back end, here is the call.

```js
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl + '/recipes', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Token token=${user.token}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        recipe: {
          recipeId: uri
        }
      })
    })
```

Then this is the route I send the call to on my backend

```js
router.post('/recipes', requireToken, (req, res) => {
  req.body.recipe.owner = req.user.id
  Recipe.create(req.body.recipe)
    .then(recipe => {
      console.log('Recipe object saved is', recipe)
      res.status(201).json({ recipe: recipe.toObject() })
    })
    .catch(err => handle(err, res))
})
```

When I do this, the correct object logs right before it sends back. Here is an example of what gets logged

```js
{ __v: 0,
  updatedAt: 2018-10-19T15:47:16.809Z,
  createdAt: 2018-10-19T15:47:16.809Z,
  recipeId: 'http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_7dae4a3b1f6e5670be3c2df5562e4782',
  owner: 5bc9fc6a3682194cdb8d6fa5,
  _id: 5bc9fc843682194cdb8d6fa7 }
```

However, when I console.log what I get back on the front end, I get this.

```js
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:4741/recipes", redirected: false, status: 201, ok: true, …}
body: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 201
statusText: "Created"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:4741/recipes"
__proto__: Response
```

On the call, it does record the action with my database, so the information gets saved, and is logged right before it should be sent back, however the proper information is not sent back.
Thank you ahead of time for any response.

Answer (score 7):

Since you're using `fetch` to make the request, the response is encapsulated in the `Response` object, and to access it you have to call the async method `json()`. Just like the following:

```
const Response = await fetch(apiUrl + '/recipes', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Token token=${user.token}`
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    recipe: {
      recipeId: uri
    }
  })
});

const json = await Response.json();
console.log(json);
```

You can play with another example in your chrome console.

```
(async () => {  
  const Response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  const res = await Response.json();
  console.log(res);
})();
```

**UPDATE**

Another way to do that is:

```
(async () => { 
  const response = await (
    await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  ).json();

  console.log(response);
})();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried .json(), and couldn't get that to work. I'm assuming I was still doing something stupid. I ended up switching up to an axios call, and that worked like a champ.